# using $.post() jQuery method for button click event

Tags: php, jquery

I have a mini-web application that populates contents of a JavaScript object as the user interacts with the page. I've added a `on('click', function() {})` 
event handler to a button element on the page.

I want to use `$.post` method in the event handler to post/submit the JavaScript object to a PHP backend and asynchronously update a 'Div' element with the data/message received from the PHP server/script.

console.log verifies the JavaScript object is OK, but I can't even receive a 'Hello World' string back from the PHP script, let alone processing the JavaScript object.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="sbButton" type="button">Submit </button> <div id="output"></div>`
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() { 
    // populates name:value pairs as user interacts on the web page 
    var vInfo = {}; 
    $('#sbButton').on('click', function() { 

        $.post('http://localhost/ReceptionVisitorKiosk/response.php'‌​, vInfo, function(data) { 
            console.log("Response Info " + data); 
            $('#output').text(data); 
        }); 
    });
}
```

**PHP:** Tried both as suggested by kyshel and robert in their replies to no help.

Comment: Show us the code please, a myriad of problems could be present, causing the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Please show your code and tell where you are having problem

Comment: Please be more specific in what exactly prevents you to receive answer from server (see developer console for clues). Try to deduce your problem  to [minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help others reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following snippet:

```
var objectToSend = {name:"Some Name", lastName:"Some last name"};
    $.post('url_to_php.php', objectToSend , function(response){
       console.log(response);
    });
```

accessing variables in php.

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$data = //some object you are returning
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

**EDIT:**

I've tested following snippet on http://phpfiddle.org/. I could not save it cause it requires registration, but you can re-paste it.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
{
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $data = "Thank you $name";
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data); 
    return false;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>
            PhpFiddle Initial Code
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin: 50px 10%;">
            <button id="mybutton" type="button">Click to See</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#mybutton").click(function() {
                // myurl can be an URL or PhpFiddle API, fopr example, 
                //var myurl = "http://main.xfiddle.com/<?php echo pf_file('jh2-qj7'); ?>";
                //console.log(myurl);
                var dataToSend = {name : "Robert"};
                $.post(window.location.href, dataToSend , function(response){
                    alert(response);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No Syntax errors in JS or PHP. 
My code:
HTML: 
`<button id="sbButton" type="button">Submit </button>
<div id="output"></div> `
JS: 
`$(function() {
// populates name:value pairs as user interacts on the web page
var vInfo = {}; 

$('#sbButton').on('click', function() {
$.post('http://localhost/ReceptionVisitorKiosk/response.php', vInfo, function(data) {
console.log("Response Info " + data); 
$('#output').text(data);
   });`

});
PHP: 
Used yours
I get error: syntaxerror json.parse unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the json data

Comment: @aj-47 your variable `vInfo` is empty, so it means it will be no POST variables to read on the server.

Comment: it is not empty, it builds dynamically as user responds on the webpage, i use - `vInfo.name = $('#name').val(); `
Doing a console.log for vInfo just before button click is: 
{ name: "testNm", company: "testCom", visiting: "testVis", phone: "02342", purpose: "General" }

Comment: What did you u se as data variable from my example?

Comment: ` $data = "Thank You" . $name; `

Answer (score 1):

## **You must check these first：**

1. does JavaScript has syntax error? (check console)
2. does your PHP has syntax or logic error?(Ex:In CentOS 7,input command`#tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log`)

If there is no error, try code below, it works fine on my server:

## Example

**index.html**

```
<button id="foo">Click</button>
<div id="receive"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function runPost(){
    var object_a={name:"mike",sex:"male"};

    $.post("post.php", object_a, function(result){
        $("#receive").html(result);
    });
}


$("#foo").click(function() {
  runPost(); 
});
</script>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php
echo '<pre>' . var_export($_POST, true) . '</pre>';

echo "hello,world~";
```

**result:**

[image]

Comment: No Syntax errors in JS or PHP. Also, Apache access.log shows POST request received OK. My code:

Comment: No Syntax errors in JS or PHP. 
My code:
HTML: 
`<button id="sbButton" type="button">Submit </button>
<div id="output"></div> `
JS: 
`$(function() {
// populates name:value pairs as user interacts on the web page
var vInfo = {}; 

$('#sbButton').on('click', function() {
$.post('http://localhost/ReceptionVisitorKiosk/response.php', vInfo, function(data) {
console.log("Response Info " + data); 
$('#output').text(data);
   });`

});
PHP: 
Used yours
Still the page doesn't update and I don't see anything in f12>console>network